# DAX calculated column with cumulative count of repeating dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have the following DAX code:

```
Tbl = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
    dDates[Date], 
    fPurchases[Ticker], 
    "Net result", SUMX( 
        fPurchases, 
        fPurchases[Shares] * ( fPurchases[Share Price] - fPurchases[Average Cost] ) 
    ) 
)
```

That produces a calculated table whose first rows look like the following:

| Date | TIcker | Net result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/24/2021 | HAPV3 | $99.00 |
| 2/26/2021 | VBBR3 | $131.81 |
| 3/1/2021 | TIMS3 | $120.12 |
| 3/1/2021 | ALSO3 | $188.64 |
| 6/28/2021 | BBDC3 | $61.71 |
| 6/28/2021 | ABEV3 | $104.50 |
| 6/28/2021 | CCRO3 | ($3.12) |
| 6/28/2021 | PSSA3 | ($127.37) |
| 6/29/2021 | MULT3 | ($27.26) |
| 6/29/2021 | ALSO3 | ($24.79) |
| 7/8/2021 | GMAT3 | $104.64 |

I've been trying to add to that table a calculated column that runs a **cumulative count of the repeating dates** from the date column (Tbl[Date]) **which should (obviously) reset back to 1 every time a new date comes by**.

The following code almost gets me there, but instead of returning a cumulative count it just returns the total occurrences of each date:

```
Cumul Count Date (Wrong) = 
CALCULATE( 
    COUNT( Tbl[Date] ), 
    FILTER( 
        ALL( Tbl ), 
        Tbl[Date] = EARLIER( Tbl[Date] ) 
    ) 
)
```

Below is the table with the calculated column produced by the above code, and an added column with the results I need:

| Date | TIcker | Net result | Cumul Count Date (WRONG) | Cumul Count Date (CORRECT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/24/2021 | HAPV3 | $99.00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2/26/2021 | VBBR3 | $131.81 | 1 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | TIMS3 | $120.12 | 2 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | ALSO3 | $188.64 | 2 | 2 |
| 6/28/2021 | BBDC3 | $61.71 | 4 | 1 |
| 6/28/2021 | ABEV3 | $104.50 | 4 | 2 |
| 6/28/2021 | CCRO3 | ($3.12) | 4 | 3 |
| 6/28/2021 | PSSA3 | ($127.37) | 4 | 4 |
| 6/29/2021 | MULT3 | ($27.26) | 2 | 1 |
| 6/29/2021 | ALSO3 | ($24.79) | 2 | 2 |
| 7/8/2021 | GMAT3 | $104.64 | 1 | 1 |

Could anyone help me get there?

It seems pretty simple, I'm just having trouble tweaking the code to get across the finish line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Column = ROWNUMBER(ALLSELECTED('Table'[Date], 'Table'[Net result], 'Table'[TIcker]), ORDERBY('Table'[Date], ASC), DEFAULT,PARTITIONBY('Table'[Date]))
```

[image]